# MathJax Spacing Issue when displaying data from wolfram api

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax, mathml

I am creating a fork of a wolfram step by step api query app. I have gotten the api interaction working fine its available here: https://abinash18.github.io/AbisWolframSolver/

The problem I have is that when I try to use the math ml output from the api it has new line characters inside of it since it is returned in json and not xml. I can remove these tags by doing a replace All but the formatting changes and the spacing between the "<mtext>"s currently my fix is using a css override to apply a 2px margin on the left and right since mathjax applies the .mtext class to the spans when parsing. I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this. here is an image of the way its supposed to be formatted vs what it currently without the css overrides looks:
Input Query:

```
verify tanθ + cotθ = secθ cscθ
```

[image: Good formating image]

[image: Bad formating image]

I was able to pipe out the parsed math jax math ml it was using and figured out that it was removing the whitespace inside the "<mtext>" tags like:

```
<mtext>cotangent </mtext>
<mtext>as </mtext>
```

To:

```
<mtext>cotangent</mtext>
<mtext>as</mtext>
```

Is there any way to stop this behavior?

I'm using MathJax 2 and I can switch to mathjax 3 if needed.

And everything that is being used to query the api and render is client sided.

Answer (score 0):

As per usual a proprietary API like wolfram of course let this slide under their slimy nose.

As per MathML Spec mtext tags cannot have trailing or leading whitespace inside them so mathjax removes this.

I solved this by replacing the \s with a &nbsp